# playing Midi notes (not files) in android

Tags: android, midi

Working on a simple keyboard for android. I found android-midi-lib from Google very useful and powerful but it seems to me it can only play midi files, but not real time midi notes as they get pressed on the keyboard.
Is there a direct way of doing this in android or what's the work around, create a midi file for every note that gets pressed?

Thanks!

SG

Comment: It might be easier to just play audio using tone generator instead of going through a midi playback engine.  When the user loads a midi file, maybe then switch to midi library to play it.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but the sound is pretty flat (just a sine wave). With midi I can make it sound like a piano

Comment: @user3438553 Have you taken a look at the project I linked to? It allows you to do precisely what you're asking for.

Comment: @DigCamara: I didn't have time last night to work on it but I went over the code really quick and it looks like it could be what I need. But I noticed it uses audioTrack, isn't that only for generating audio? I'm still going to give it a shot. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @segbar You're right. It's for generating audio. I'm going to change my answer a bit to add a different library which would be able to generate MIDI output

Answer (score 4):

I've had quite a bit of success using the Bare Bone MIDI Driver written by bill the farmer (github project [here](https://github.com/billthefarmer/mididriver)).

You'll have to deal with some issues and also extract the low-level library from an emulator/Android device but it works very well (if you want to see it in action, take a look at my app in my profile).

There's also pd Library for Android  ([github link](https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android)) which got MIDI support just about a year ago (so [sayeth Peter Brinkmann](http://libpd.cc/2013/02/new-midi-support-in-pd-for-android/), its creator)